# Which three of these six plants should I get?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-recommendations

I am getting three plants. But I have selected six plants from websites.

They are:

1. Janet Craig
2. Chinese Evergreen
3. Fancy leaved Caladium
4. Massangeana Plant
5. Philodendron
6. Snake Plant

Snake plant is well known and so I am definitely getting one. However, I don't have much knowledge about plants, and I want the best plant from the above mentioned plants. Best in terms of following:

1. low light requirement
2. dry to mid-humid environment
3. that can survive in winter and summer
4. best air-purification(one guy guided me to a blog which said that all plants are good at air-purification, but I want the best of them.)

I can only get three plants. I know this is sort of a personal choice but as I have said before, I don't have much knowledge about plants. I am confused as to which one to get that meets the above mentioned requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with all of these plants.  Let's make it clear from the start that when you talk about significant air purification by indoor tropical plants it only been demonstrated in a sealed environment under extremely high light conditions.  See the [original](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930073077.pdf) and follow on study [here](https://ia800300.us.archive.org/35/items/nasa_techdoc_19930072988/19930072988.pdf).

Best plants for low light of your selection:

- Chinese Evergreen or [Aglaonema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaonema)
- Dracaena Massangea and its relative Janet Craig

Best plants for a dry (low humidity) environment

- Sanseveria

The fancy leaved [caladium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caladium) tends to go dormant if it gets too dry. The papery thin leaves have brilliant markings but do better in a high light and higher humidity environment.

Philodendrons can be great plants but there is such a variety of types.  They range from weakly climbing vines to massive plants like [Philodendron Selloum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philodendron_bipinnatifidum)

If you are just starting with plants I would get an aglaonema.  They normally grow in low light areas and can be quite tough and easy to propagate.  Unlike Mass Canes or Janet Craig's they do not have a sensitivity to fluoride in the water that can give brown tips and eventual leaf spotting.

Comment: Excellent Kevinsky..I'd like to add another plant that the OP did not mention.  Aspidistr elatior or Iron Plant. Never have I known a tougher plant, vigorous plant that can thrive with virtually no light.  Otherwise I totally agree with your selections...

Comment: @stormy you are right, great plant but not commonly seen in the trade.  The highlight for this plant seems to have been in the Victorian age.  It probably needs a new name and an ad campaign to become popular again.

Comment: I've found this plant in perfect condition beneath a massive deck unloved for half a decade.  No light, no fert, no water?  Gees, impressed me!